# OpenCL passing multiple arrays of different sizes to kernel

Tags: opencl

I want to pass two arrays of different sizes to the kernel, how can I set the `cl_ndrange`?

With only one array of size `NUM_VALUES`, the range can be easily set as

```
cl_ndrange range = { // 6
            1, // The number of dimensions to use.
            {0, 0, 0}, // The offset in each dimension. To specify
            // that all the data is processed, this is 0
            // in the test case. // 7
            {NUM_VALUES, 0, 0}, // The global range—this is how many items
            // IN TOTAL in each dimension you want to
            // process.
            {NULL, 0, 0} // The local size of each workgroup. This
            // determines the number of work items per
            // workgroup. It indirectly affects the
            // number of workgroups, since the global
            // size / local size yields the number of
            // workgroups. In this test case, there are
            // NUM_VALUE / wgs workgroups.
        };
```

But I don't know what to do for two arrays with different sizes. In my case, one array is actually used as input for calculation, while another is used to for lookups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to figure out what exactly your kernel is going to do. Write your kernel code, and by the time you're done with it, you'll probably know the launch configuration that this kernel requires.

Comment: does the look up table change during kernel execution? about how many elements are in each array? what data types are you using?

Comment: The NDRange should be sized for the amount of work to be done, which is usually the size of your _output_ array. The input array might match (if the work is 1:1) but the lookup array probably won't (and that's OK).